# Should I use a composite key, or will it cause too much processing overhead?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on the efficiency of MySQL server, and have a very large database which utilizes several composite keys, would server performance be improved by de-normalizing data and not using composite keys?  I am requesting an "in general" answer, due to non-disclosure I cannot post any code or database schema.

Comment: *I am requesting an "in general" answer* In general it depends.

Comment: Usually not a good idea to give in to performance over normalization I think

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and "in general" it does depend you are right.  Didn't know if anyone had any hard and fast rules about database performance with relation to composite keys.

Comment: Know what you could do with hard and fast rules? :P jk

Comment: If you are using MySQL, add a MySQL tag and remove sql-server. Those are different DBMS products.

Comment: You can always give a representative schema describing your situation. Not giving any details is like asking "How can I make my car faster?" without even talking about what kind of car, and what "faster" means.

Comment: @tadman......if someone asked how to make a car faster I would say better engine, better tires, nitrous...etc....you know....the things a standard car may not have.  You know what a car is, and how it works.  You comment is what I consider quibbling about a question.  "Faster" means less time.  And you don't know my business or company, I cannot and will not even come close to disclosing anything about the database, even a schema.  Sorry you disagree, but you are speaking above your knowledge level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a large database, you shouldn't denormalize the data--that would be criminal to your client etc. The secret to speed is always more indexes. Figure out which queries they use the most and optimize those by looking at their query plans. Ideally, you want to see the word "seek" instead of "scan". If you still see the word "scan", just keeping adding more indexes to your database until you see the word "seek".

You'd be surprised how much you could gain by getting a better understanding of exactly how they're using the database and what's really slowing it down. De-normalization, unfortunately, is a last resort. They'll thank you later when they won't have to create obscenely complex queries because there's no other way to accomplish anything, thanks to you giving in to more short-sighted solutions. You should be thinking more long-term both for them and for your practice imho. Cheers